# Set widget size to half of another's size

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt, I have a `QDialog` with two `QTreeView` objects. I want one of them to always be half the height of the other one, and maintain this when I resize my dialog. I add the in a `QVBoxLayout`.

How can I do this?

Comment: [setVerticalStretch](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#setVerticalStretch) sounds like it should do that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the QVBoxLayout::addWidget() method's `stretch` argument, like this:

```
layout->addWidget(smallWidget, 1);
layout->addWidget(bigWidget,   2);
```